# How to add offset to a character pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a the following declarations :-

```
char szsrcBuf[10000];    /* stores main bufer */
int iOff2Verify;         /* offset to start of verify area*/
int iLen2Verify;         /* length of data to verify */
```

Now when I call the function with the following parameters :-

```
/* process data to verify */
if ((iRet = Verify_Mid(&mach, (char *)(szsrcBuf + (int)iOff2Verify),
                iLen2Verify)) != 0)
    break;
```

The signature for the Verify_Mid() looks like :-

```
int CALLBACK Verify_Mid(bsapi_id *mach, char *inputData, int inputDataLen);
```

Things work great.

-------------------xxx above is the is my first way of coding, that works. xxx----------------------

However my code started getting big enough, where I need to re-structure the function of my original call. So I split out the part where I am calling Verify_Mid.... as such:-

```
iRet = Verify_Request(x, y, szsrcBuf, z, &iOff2Verify, iLen2Verify, (char *)abc, &iabcLen);
```

The signature for the new helper function Verify_Request is:-

```
int CALLBACK Verify_Request(unsigned char *x, int y, unsigned char *szsrcBuf, char *z, 
                            int *iOff2Verify, int iLen2Verify, char *abc, int *iabcLen);
```

Now inside my Verfiy_Request () :-

```
do{
   ..... stuff....


/* process data to verify */
if ((iRet = Verify_Mid(&mach, (char *)(szsrcBuf + (int)iOff2Verify),
        iLen2Verify)) != 0)
        break;

.... stuff .....

}while(0);
```

Until this point everything looks ok (on the apparent), however when I go to my Verfiy_Mid (), there is an error reading the 2nd parameter (char * inputData)... I have tried a couple of things with how I am passing the 2nd parameter, but to no avail... can anyone help me understand how to add the offset and then correctly pass it as a parameter to my next function ?

Comment: explain please? English is not my first language, I need help understanding why casts are not required?

Comment: can you please rearrange your code and send a more focused question? it's all a bit of a mess...

Comment: Remove all casts from your code unless you can explain precisey why each one is necessary. Note, "the compiler complains if I remove it" is not an explanation. If the compiler complains, figure out what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `iOff2Verify` as a pointer to function `Verify_Request(...);`

Therefore in order to actually pass data stored in that pointer, your call to `Verify_Mid(...)` needs to reflect that as well.

```
do{

/* process data to verify */
if ((iRet = Verify_Mid(&mach, (char *)(szsrcBuf + (*iOff2Verify)),
    iLen2Verify)) != 0)
    break;
}while(0);
```

By the way, if you don't need to change value of `iOff2Verify` in `Verify_Request`, there is no need to pass it as a pointer, just regular int would suffice and it would save you all the trouble of pointer debugging, which is usually just pure hell

Comment: Also `iOff2Verify` is `int *` anyway, so casting `*iOff2Verify` to `int` is pointless... it's already `int` when dereferenced.

Comment: thanks! that helped. coming from C# to C (pointers) is different.

Comment: @Dmitri true, I just left it there from copying OP's code. Will remove it.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback from both of you. that cleared up a couple of things for me. thank you